# How to get an element by id created in react native webview?

Tags: javascript, react-native

How to get a `<div>` element by id created in react native webview.

The code below stores the value if the `sheetdata` div in the `ele` variable.

```
var ele = document.getElementById('sheetdata').value;
```

In my react native app, the element `sheetdata` is created in the webview. Now, I want to access this element by `id` in my external js code.

Here is my index.ios.js where `sheetdata` is defined:

```
let HTML = `
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="workbookControl"></div>
            <div id="tableeditor">editor goes here</div>
            <div id="msg" onclick="this.innerHTML='&nbsp;';"></div>
            <textarea name="savestr" id="sheetdata">
              TextAreaVal
            </textarea>
      </body>
    </html>
    `;

    AppGeneral.initializeApp();
```

Here is my AppGeneral file where I want to access the `sheetdata` element:

```
export function initializeApp(){
 var ele = document.getElementById("sheetdata").value;
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Can't find variable document